# Resizing Window Glitch in C

Tags: c, winapi

I need to make a WinAPI window in C. Not C++. In C, when I make the window, it has a problem with resizing. When I resize it to be bigger, it makes a black background with odd white patches in it. The only way to solve this is by making it the original size. It doesn't happen with C++. How can I fix this? It compiles without errors.

At normal size:
[It displays correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VrWU.png)

Maximized:
[It makes a strange effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpwr3.png)

Code:
**wmain.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

const wchar_t* szWndClassName = L"WindowClass"; const wchar_t* szWndName = L"Notepad";
int width = 600, height = 400;
HINSTANCE hInst; HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASS wc;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

RECT rect;

int CenterWindow(HWND parent_window, int width, int height)
{
    GetClientRect(parent_window, &rect);
    rect.left = (rect.right / 2) - (width / 2);
    rect.top = (rect.bottom / 2) - (height / 2);
    return 0;
}
```

**wmain.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "wmain.h"

#pragma warning (disable: 28251)
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpszCMDArgs, int nCMDShow)
{
    hInst = hThisInst;

    wc.lpszClassName = szWndClassName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(wc.hInstance, L"IDC_ARROW");
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(wc.hInstance, L"Resource Files/Images/Notepad.ico");

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"RegisterClassW failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);

        return 1;
    }

    CenterWindow(GetDesktopWindow(), width, height);

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWndClassName, szWndName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, rect.left, rect.top, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateWindowW failed!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);

        return 2;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCMDShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wp)
            {

            }
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wp, lp);
    }
}
```

##### EDIT


To fix this, add this to your WNDCLASS properties:

```
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
```

Comment: Why are you using `WNDCLASS` instead of `WNDCLASSEX`

Comment: @rkosegi I don't know to do that. I tried adding it, but it has the same result.

Comment: @GovindParmar Because WNDCLASSEX needs a whole bunch of properties for ```RegisterClassEx()``` to work.

Comment: Changing the fields of `wc` doesn't have any effect after you've used it in a call to `RegisterClass`. Consider getting a [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either set a window background in the `WNDCLASS`, or implement the `WM_PAINT` message to redraw the window.

Comment: I found out the answer already with the help of @rkosegi. But this made it fall in place.